# Remove items with values beyond average

Tags: c#, integer, average

I have a list of integers, i.e.:

```
 List<int> test = new List<int>() {
     5, 5, 4, 0, 1, 23456732, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3
 };
```

I would like to calculate an average for the integers within the list, but without taking into account any abnormal values (like the one in the middle). Is there any method in the List object I could use for it? What would be the best way to approach it?

Comment: How do you define `abnormal`?

Comment: You probably want the mean, not the average.

Comment: What makes 23456732 "abnormal"?

Comment: Based on WHAT you need to ignore 23456732?

Comment: Maybe you want to calculate the average and standard deviation, and then calculate a new average of only those data points that are closer than three times the standard deviation to the original average? This is a common definition for "abnormal" when data points are assumed to follow a normal distribution. But is it your definition of "abnormal"? You really need to think about your requirements, only when you have them defined you can implement them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
var average = test.Average();
```

If you want to exclude some of the values then you need to filter them:

```
// average of numbers less than 100
var average = test.Where(i => i < 100).Average();
```

You can define your own function which will check whether given number is normal:

```
var average = test.Where(i => IsNormal(i)).Average();
// method
bool IsNormal(int number)
{
    // your logic here
    return true;// or false
}
```

Comment: Or `test.Where(i => IsNormal(i)).Average();` and let the definition of `IsNormal` to the author of the question :)

Comment: @GrzegorzSławecki: lol

Comment: Good call @GrzegorzSławecki, I'll add it to my answer, we'll leave the rest for Bartosz. Thanks!

Comment: I know that my answer may be wrong, depending on definion of `abnormal`, but I'm still not convinced that this answer deserves downvote.

Comment: Since this answer has been accepted as the best answer I guess I was right after all, yet downvote is still here, without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could first calculate the `median` and then only use values for the calculation that are only a given factor away from the `median` (10 in the example):

```
public double GetResult(List<int> values)
{
    int median = Median(values);
    return values.Where(x => Math.Abs(x - median) < 10 * median).Average();
}

public static int Median(IEnumerable<int> list)
{
    List<int> orderedList = list
      .OrderBy(numbers => numbers)
      .ToList();

    int listSize = orderedList.Count;
    int result;

    if (listSize % 2 == 0) // even
    {
        int midIndex = listSize / 2;
        result = ((orderedList.ElementAt(midIndex - 1) +
               orderedList.ElementAt(midIndex)) / 2);
    }
    else // odd
    {
        double element = (double)listSize / 2;
        element = Math.Round(element, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        result = orderedList.ElementAt((int)(element - 1));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Median calculation taken from this page: http://www.remondo.net/calculate-mean-median-mode-averages-csharp/